# After installing catalina visual studio code can't find git

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

Gitlens no longer can find git.
I have installed the latest version of git 2.23.0
I have searched the internet but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 13):

Add `$ xcode-select --install` into your terminal and restart Visual Studio code.

This worked for me.